# Android Studio Error about sdk

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

## Android Studio Sdk Problem

I have install android studio but it give error that sdk not found.i have already download stand alone tool of sdk for android studio but i don't know how can configure sdk on android studio.

[image]

Comment: checked running your SDK manager ?..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633035/no-android-sdk-found-android-studio

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14932974/android-sdk-not-found-error

Comment: post the error message which you are getting.

Comment: do  you download SDK from https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html...

Comment: @utility   I did not find Install new software option in help menu of Android Studio of 1.1.0

Comment: You have to install the JDK; updated my anwser.

Answer (score 1):

If you have already the stand-alone SDK installed the only thing you have to do is let your Android-Studio know where it is.

`File > Project Structure > SDK Location`

`EDIT:`

You have to download the official JDK 7 from [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html) and install it (JKD 1.7).
If you install it with default settings set your JDK path to somthing like `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7`

Comment: I can not add image because i have 9 reputation it require 10 can you vote up for me?

Comment: I have java version "1.7.0_76" install

Comment: I see you use ubuntu, if you have JDK7 installed the folder of the JDK should be `/usr/lib/jvm/`